# A chart element with the name already exists in the 'ChartAreaCollection'

Tags: c#, charts

i'm working with chart, when i ran the program my chart is working well but everytime i clicked the form chart it shows me.

> A chart element with the name already exists in the
>   'ChartAreaCollection'.

here is my code :

```
   public void chart1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        chart1.ChartAreas.Add("fitness");
        chart1.Series["fitness"].Color = Color.Brown;


        for (int i = 0; i < Form1.listFitnessTerbaik.Length; i++)
        {
            chart1.Series["fitness"].Points.AddXY(0, Form1.listBestFitness[i]) ;



        }

        this.chart1.Titles.Clear();

    }
```

what should i do? thanks before for the advice..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this post is really old, but I was having the same issue.  I ended up using the 'IsUniqueName' to check to see if the series already exists.  Something like this:

```
    private void createNewSeries(String SeriesName)
    {
        if(chart1.Series.IsUniqueName(SeriesName))
        {
            chart1.Series.Add(SeriesName);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ite seems like there is a duplicate key in some dictionary. Before adding a key, try checking if it has already been added. May be something like.

```
if (!chart1.ChartAreas.Contains("fitness"))
     chart1.ChartAreas.Add("fitness");
```

Comment: helo mehmet..i've try but it still have an error in if (chart1.ChartAreas.Contains("fitness"))

Comment: @Christy ChartAreas.Contains() does not accept string. But Series does. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, for me the answer was to first clear the series like this:

```
_chart.Series.Clear()
```

This is important if you build your Charts dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a series exist before adding it:

```
if (!chart1.ChartAreas[0].Series.Contains("fitness"))
     chart1.ChartAreas[0].Series.Add("fitness");
```